# setOnItemClickListener is not working in listview while i use imagebutton inside custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

In ListView i add TextView and ImageButton through **CustomAdapter** class (which  extends ArrayAdapter).when i add  onClickListener to ImageButton in CustomAdapter class then ListView onItemClickListener is not working.In case i want to select multiple list and also single list that listener is not working and parallel ImageButton onClickListener works.***I want both ListView and ImageButton onClickListener and onItemClickListener works in my Activity***.How to solve this issue?

Anyone give some suggestion!

Code Below:

```
public class ViewHolder {
     TextView username;
     ImageButton download;
     TextView time;
     ImageView contactpic;  }

    public interface ButtonListener {
        public void onButtonClickListner(int position, VoiceMailRecords value);
    }

    public void setCustomButtonListner(ButtonListener listener) {
        this.customListner = listener;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            if(convertView==null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recorded_item, parent, false);
                //TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                viewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.callingTime);
                //TextView number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.callerNumber);
                viewHolder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.callerName);
                viewHolder.contactpic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_round);
                //   ImageView checked = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.is_checked);
                viewHolder.download = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.is_download);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            final VoiceMailRecords user = getItem(position);
            viewHolder.username.setText(user.getCallerNumber());

            return convertView;


    }
```

In Activity

```
voiceMailRecordAdapter=new VoiceMailRecordAdapter(this,voiceMailRecords,this);
voicemailList.setAdapter(voiceMailRecordAdapter);
voiceMailRecordAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

voicemailList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(ListVoiceMailRecord.this,"Position :"+position+" clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
});

@Override
public void onButtonClickListner(int position, VoiceMailRecords value) {
    Log.d(TAG, "VoiceMailApi onButtonClickListner " );
    Toast.makeText(ListVoiceMailRecord.this,"onButtonClickListner :"+position+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: i update my code @JayPatel

Comment: @RevathiManoharan can you please elaborate little bit clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set **`focusableInTouchMode`** as ***false*** for your ImageButton.

Add this line in your imageButton

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

And **`instead of onItemClick()`** try ***onClick() for convertview***,

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Log.d("clicked"," yes");
      }
}
```

Comment: still ListView onClickListener not working only ImageButton Listener works

Comment: Do you mean onitemclick() or onclick(). If onclick(), why do you need onclick listener for listview.

Comment: I mean onitemclick()

Comment: You can try onclicklistener for convertview. And it works in my case

Comment: yes in your adapter, in getview() method, use clickListener for the convertview

Answer (score 0):

Many time `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` will do the trick but if these won't work then Sometimes the List will not be able to make the Click Listener. In this case, you might have to add one more attribute.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

And this attribute has to be added to the topmost layout of your XML where you have provided the ListView elements.

Comment: still not working @Jay Patel let you know i am using RelationLayout

Answer (score 0):

you can add interface in adapter and can handle click in activity or fragment

```
     public interface  ButtonClick{
            void Click(View view,int position);
        }
    public Adapter(Context context, ButtonClick buttonclick){

            this.buttonclick=buttonclick;
          this.context=context;
        }
        ButtonClick buttonclick;

     yourimage.setTag(position);
           yourimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos= (int) v.getTag();
                    if(buttonclick!=null){
                        buttonclick.Click(v,pos);

                    }

                }
            });
```

You can handle click in activity when you set adapter

```
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(Youractivity.this, new Adapter.ButtonClick() {
                        @Override
                        public void Click(View view, int position) {
                            // your logic
                        }
                    });
```

Hope this helps .

```
this is how i have implemented in multiple projects
```